# Spring session attribute lost on page calling itself

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

So, I've got a very simple 2 controller Spring MVC app. First controller logs user in and puts it on session like this

`model.addAttribute( "user", userDto );`

Second controller displays project based on `projectId`, but expects user to be in session.

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes( "user" )
@RequestMapping( value = "/project" )
public class ProjectController {
...
    @GetMapping( "/{projectId}" )
    public String get( @PathVariable( "projectId" ) String projectId, @SessionAttribute( "user" ) UserDto userDto, Model model ) {
...
```

First call to this controller works just fine. However, if user changes project on UI ( through `select onchange="'location = /project/<some-id-from-select>"` ) I'm getting error message from Spring:

`[org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestBindingException: Missing session attribute 'user' of type UserDto]`

How is it possible that session attribute gets lost after one request? No filters, security or session/request specific configurations are defined in the project.

Comment: For starters I would strongly suggest to ditch this approach and use Spring Security to secure your application, don't roll your own security solution. Second yuo are using a JS function to issue a request, does that include the proper session cookie?

Comment: So, all I need is to send back cookies I've got from server?

Comment: To restore the session yes, else it won't work. However normally your browser should handle that transparantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually it got fixed much easier: I've forgotten to add `@SessionAttributes( "user" )` in first controller, where `model.addAttribute( "user", userDto );` gets called. After adding it, everything works like a charm.